# Installing numpy from

Tags: python, macos, numpy, installation

(I looked at many answers on here but similar questions were not answered or didn't address my question).

I use numpy + scipy + matplotlib on Mac-OSX 10.8.5. I have numpy 1.6.1 on my machine and using python 2.7.5 in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/`. I've been running with that configuration for several months running from Idle or the command line.

I just upgraded to matplotlib 1.3.1 from the .dmg file at Sourceforge. The install worked fine and I can see the correct version in `matplotlib.__version__`. However, I cannot use it because it claims I need numpy 1.7 or higher. So I downloaded the numpy-1.8.0 dmg file from Sourceforge and installed it using the Mac installer. The installer claims to have done it correctly, but `numpy.__version__` is still 1.6.1!!! I've done the installation multiple times (each time successfully according to the Mac installer) with the same result.

I had no problem upgrading matplotlib to 1.3.1 and scipy to 0.13 using their respective .dmg files at Sourceforge. I don't see why numpy should not install the same way. I must have upgraded it the same way in the past, but I can't remember.

I run Python from Idle as well as from the command line and don't want to go to some other distribution like Macports, etc. I've been using Python this way for 4 years and don't understand why numpy is not being updated. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Correction. My python version runs from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`. When I look at the site-packages directory, I can see the numpy directory and that many of the files have been updated as of today. There is also a `numpy-1.8.0-py2.7.egg-info/` directory.

Comment: What do you get if you run `numpy.__file__` and `matplotlib.__file__` in the python terminal?

Comment: Hi, you have identified something important:

numpy: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/__init__.pyc`

matplotlib:
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc`

scipy:
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/__init__.pyc`

So numpy is updating a different directory than matplotlib and scipy! Do you have a fix for that? Thanks, in the meantime for identifying the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure how dangerous it is, but I would try copying `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/nump‌​y/` to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/`, but to be safer, first move, if it exists `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/` to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy_old/`

Comment: So the issue is two different python installations, (1) the original "apple" one in `/System/Library/...` (which I don't use) vs (2) the user version in `/Library/...` which has the 2.7.5 version installed from python.org. The apple installer for numpy updates the original Apple installation while all others update the user-installed one. Is there a way to easily fix the numpy installation?

Comment: Ah, missed your comment. I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: I wrote a better description in the answer.

Comment: It's not going to work. The directory '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/nump‌​‌​y/' was not updated (all dates are from a few months ago), but `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/n‌​umpy/` was updated today. Yet when I run python (from shell or Idle) it still finds numpy in the first location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three solutions, one is the one given in my comment, but an easier one might be to change your `PYTHONPATH`.  On the command line:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/:$PYTHONPATH
```

To make the change permanent, put that line in your

```
~/.bashrc
```

file.

---

From my comment:
I'm not sure how dangerous it is, but to just move the installation to be with your others, you could try

```
mv /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/n‌​umpy/ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/n‌​umpy_old/
cp /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/nump‌​‌​y/ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/n‌​umpy/
```

---

Finally, you could try using `pip` to install numpy.  To see where `pip` is installed, type this in terminal:

```
which pip
```

If it's where you want it to be (`/Library/...`), then all you have to do is

```
pip install numpy
```

Comment: Actually, I ran pip before I posted the question, but forgot to mention that. pip is indeed located in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip`. However, when I ran it, I had to type `pip install numpy --upgrade` because pip found an earlier version. I don't think that the PYTHONPATH solution will help when running from Idle, which I do quite frequently when debugging.

Comment: It seems you'll have to look at `import sys; sys.path` and see where it's looking for numpy.  Modifying `sys.path` is a bit tricky though.

Comment: Sigh... I tried installing numpy-1.7.1 afterwards. Now when I run python from the shell I get `numpy.__version__ = 1.7.1`. Good. Idle still claims that numpy is 1.6.1. Bad.  Then I installed matplotlob-1.3.1 to see if I can run my program from the shell correctly. But when I run my program from the shell, python complains that matplotlib.pyplot is incompatible with my installed numpy, which it claims is version 6, even though when I ran python from the shell it claimed that numpy was 1.7.1. I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: By 'shell' do you mean the interpreter (what you get when you just type `python` on the terminal), or from terminal, as in `python my_script.py`?  Also, from terminal, what do `which python` and `which idle` give you?

Comment: Yes, the first non-blank entry in sys.path is `/System/Library/...` with `/Library/...` following a few entries later. I totally don't understand why it is set that way when I've been using the second version since I bought the Mac in July and installed python 2.7.5. This is totally messed up.

Comment: Yes, I mean the interpreter, when I type python as a shell command.

Comment: Hold on: I use python myscript.py when I run a program

Comment: Now when I use the python interpreter, I get `numpy.__version__ = 1.6.1`, instead of 1.7.1. I have no idea why the version reverted to 1.6.1. Running a python script from the shell always gives me 1.6.1. I would consider installing python again if I knew how to start from scratch. This inconsistency in installing and using numpy relative to other installs is terrible .

Comment: OK, I can see what happened and your comments pointed me to the solution. All my updates, numpy included, updated the `/Library/...` version of python, not touching the Apple-installed original `/System/Library...`. However, the Apple version also had its own version of numpy which was picked because sys.path had `/System/Library` as the first entry. I merely renamed `/numpy` to `/numpy_old` in the `/System/Library` version and that forced the system to look in the new `/Library/...` version of `numpy/` that had been there all along. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I tried to up vote your answer, but my reputation is not high enough to do so. Perhaps you'll get your reward in heaven. :-)