# numpy 'module' object has no attribute 'stack'

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to run some code (which is not mine), where is used 'stack' from numpy library.

Looking into documentation, stack really exists in numpy: 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html

but when I run the code, I got:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'stack'
```

any idea how to fix this.
code extract:

```
s_t = np.stack((x_t, x_t, x_t, x_t), axis = 2)
```

do I need some old libraries?

Thanks.

EDIT:
for some reason, python uses older version of numpy library. pip2 freeze prints "numpy==1.10.4". I've also reinstalled numpy and I've got "Successfully installed numpy-1.10.4", but printing np.version.version in code gives me 1.8.2.

Comment: How do you import numpy?

Comment: It is only present since numpy 1.10 ... you are probably using an older version

Comment: as usual: import numpy as np

Comment: You missed the fine print New in version 1.10.0. you probably have an older version of numpy  import numpy as np  then np.version.version will give you the info

Comment: from  pip freeze: 
numpy==1.10.4

Comment: interesting, I am getting version 1.8.2 when using in code print np.version.version. how do I fix this?

Comment: I've edited question with new findings.

Comment: @SnurkaBill was it not due to multiple versions on your is? Please let us know if the answers below are not sufficient so we can further help you.

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple python installations, and pip is not part of the same one as python. Use `python -m pip` instead to ensure they're the same one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `numpy.stack` is new; it [appeared in `numpy == 1.10.0`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html).  If you can't get that version running on your system, the code can be found at (near the end)

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/f4cc58c80df5202a743bddd514a3485d5e4ec5a4/numpy/core/shape_base.py

I need to examine it a bit more, but the working part of the function is:

```
sl = (slice(None),) * axis + (_nx.newaxis,)
expanded_arrays = [arr[sl] for arr in arrays]
return _nx.concatenate(expanded_arrays, axis=axis)
```

So it adds a `np.newaxis` to each array, and then concatenate on that.  So like, `vstack`, `hstack` and `dstack` it adjusts the dimensions of the inputs, and then uses `np.concatenate`.  Nothing particularly new or magical.

So if `x` is `(2,3)` shape, `x[:,np.newaxis]` is `(2,1,3)`, `x[:,:,np.newaxis]` is `(2,3,1)` etc.

If `x_t` is 2d, then

```
np.stack((x_t, x_t, x_t, x_t), axis = 2)
```

is probably the equivalent of

```
np.dstack((x_t, x_t, x_t, x_t))
```

creating a new array that has size 4 on axis 2.

Or:

```
tmp = x_t[:,:,None]
np.concatenate((tmp,tmp,tmp,tmp), axis=2)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is likely have 2 numpy libraries, one in your System libraries, and the other in your python's site packages which is maintained by pip. You have a few options to fix this.

- You should [reorder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34748817/1435522) the libraries in `sys.path` so your pip installed numpy library comes in front the native numpy library. Check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19869277/1435522) to fix your path permanently.
- Also look into [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) or [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), which will allow you to work with specific versions of a package when you have multiple versions on your system.
- Here's another [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27370090/1435522) about how to ensure pip installs the library on your user path (System Library).